# Animate Widget back to it's previews state on press of another Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I created a tab Widget which one can press one tab and it highlights and animates, but after pressing another tab the previews tab should animate back to it's previews state.

use the blow code to run on your IDE.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AnimatedTabsOne extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 300.0,
      height: 60.0,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
          color: Colors.white,
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black26,
              offset: Offset(0, 3.5),
//            spreadRadius: 0.0,
              blurRadius: 4.0,
            ),
          ]),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: <Widget>[
          BuildTab(),
          BuildTab(),
          BuildTab(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BuildTab extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BuildTabState createState() => _BuildTabState();
}

class _BuildTabState extends State<BuildTab>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Animation<double> animation;
  AnimationController controller;

  bool isVisible = false;
  bool setActiveBackgroundColor = false;

  animateNow() {
    controller =
        AnimationController(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200), vsync: this);
    controller.forward();
    animation = Tween<double>(begin: 50, end: 150).animate(controller)
      ..addListener(() => setState(() {
            setActiveBackgroundColor = true;
            isVisible = true;
          }));
//      ..addStatusListener((AnimationStatus status) {
//        if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
//          controller.reverse();
//          setState(() {
//            setActiveBackgroundColor = false;
//            isVisible = false;
//          });
//        }
//      });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(
        "setActiveBackgroundColor $setActiveBackgroundColor, isVisible: $isVisible");
    return InkWell(
      key: UniqueKey(),
      onTap: () => animateNow(),
      child: Container(
        width: animation?.value ?? 50,
        height: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
          color: setActiveBackgroundColor == true ? Colors.blue : Colors.white,
        ),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.home),
            Flexible(
              child: Visibility(visible: isVisible, child: Text("Home")),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to use global keys, and call the callback function in another way but it did not do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use `AnimatedContainer`. I simplified your code. There are multiple solutions, everything depends on you but if you just that functionality, this is a nice pattern with minimum rebuild trigger:

```
class AnimatedTabsOne extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AnimatedTabsOneState createState() => _AnimatedTabsOneState();
}

class _AnimatedTabsOneState extends State<AnimatedTabsOne> {
  int index;
  final myTabs = [BuildTab(), BuildTab(), BuildTab()];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 300.0,
      height: 60.0,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
          color: Colors.white,
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black26,
              offset: Offset(0, 3.5),
//            spreadRadius: 0.0,
              blurRadius: 4.0,
            ),
          ]),
      child: Row(
        children: List<Widget>.from(
          myTabs.map((tab) {
            final index = myTabs.indexOf(tab);
            return GestureDetector(
              child: BuildTab(isVisible: this.index == index),
              onTap: () {
                if (this.index != index) {
                  setState(() {
                    this.index = index;
                  });
                }
              },
            );
          }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BuildTab extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isVisible;

  BuildTab({this.isVisible = false});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      width: isVisible ? 150 : 50,
      height: double.infinity,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
        color: isVisible ? Colors.blue : Colors.white,
      ),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(Icons.home),
          Flexible(
            child: Visibility(visible: isVisible, child: Text("Home")),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: with this solution I am unable to sort the icons in the tab-bar

Comment: @key I changed the code as you want, now it's identical to yours.